# How do I make my bot tell if the number given was higher or lower then the answer? [discord.py]

Tags: python, discord, bots, discord.py

I'm making a number guessing game thing, and I'm wondering how I can make it tell you if your answer was higher or lower then the answer? Here is my code so far:

````
async def number(ctx):
    await ctx.send('I\'m thinking of a number from one to ten. Try to guess which number!')
    number = random.randint(1, 10)
    answer = await client.wait_for('message', check=lambda message: message.author == ctx.author and message != "")
    answer = answer.content

    loop_counter = 0
    while answer.lower() != number:
        loop_counter += 1
        if loop_counter >= 2:
            await ctx.send(f'sorry dude, the correct number was {number}')
            break
        await ctx.send('Incorrect, try again')
        answer = await client.wait_for('message', check=lambda message: message.author == ctx.author and message != "")
        answer = answer.content

        if answer.lower() == number:
            "[testing]" ```
Thanks!
````

Comment: Couldn't find a solution..

Answer (score 0):

Within your `while` loop you can add an `if-else` loop as well.

```
while answer.lower() != number:
    if answer.lower()<number:
        #Do things if the number is lower
    else: 
        #Do things if the number is higher
    loop_counter += 1
    if loop_counter >= 2:
        await ctx.send(f'sorry dude, the correct number was {number}')
        break
```

Note: Although normally when you're checking if a number is higher / lower you couldn't use `else` because the numbers may be equal, seeing as if they were equal the loop wouldn't start, you can use `else` here

Comment: Any `#` in a code means ignore this line. Replace the `#` with whatever code you like

Answer (score 0):

At first, you can't do `if answer.lower() == number:` because `answer` is a `str` object but `number` is a `integer`. So you can't compare them. And also you don't have to do `wait_for` for 2 times. You can add it also in to the while loop. You can use this:

```py
@client.command()
async def number(ctx):
    await ctx.send('I\'m thinking of a number from one to ten. Try to guess which number!')
    number = random.randint(1, 10)
    loop_counter = 0
    while loop_counter < 2:
        anwser = client.wait_for('message', check=lambda message: message.author == ctx.author)
        try:
            answ = int(answer.content) # here it will try to return answer to a integer.
        except ValueError:
            await ctx.send('Please just type number.') # if it's not integer, then it will pass and send a warning.
            pass
        if answ == number:
            await ctx.send('You found the number.') # if user founds the answer, it will send a message and ends the loop.
            return
        else:
            await ctx.send('Sorry, wrong answer. Answer is higher.') if number-answ<0 else await ctx.send('Sorry, wrong answer. Answer is lower.')
            loop_counter += 1
    await ctx.send(f"Sorry, you couldn't find the answer. Answer was {number}")
```

Comment: Sorry, I typed one letter wrong. Change the `anwser = client.wait_for` to `answer = client.wait_for`.

Comment: That removed all errors.. But now nothing happens after I try to input a number